# Why can't dict be remove from a list of duplicate dicts

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I scraped data from a website but now the  problem is that  I can't remove duplicate dicts. The main problem is that regular ways are  not working since some items contains dicts themselves.

```
[
{
    "content": {
        "link": "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vVIhIn8Omz6fGmeriCDilOlKQhAOBItL",
        "title": "שיחו\"ק"
    },
    "id": "month_1_farbrengen_1_content",
    "event_title": "יום א' דר\"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך",
    "event_link": "https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01"
},
{
    "content": {
        "link": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q6o-wEkpAsvRQIaJqSqcCOkBZhQAAdYI/view?usp=drivesdk",
        "title": "תו\"מ התוועדויות"
    },
    "id": "month_1_farbrengen_1_content",
    "event_title": "יום א' דר\"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך",
    "event_link": "https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01"
},
{
    "content": {
        "link": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V1sXWx_Jqbn2f_2P40v_DlqlHfXB1u-0/view?usp=sharing",
        "title": "Proceeding Together Vol. 3"
    },
    "id": "month_1_farbrengen_1_content",
    "event_title": "יום א' דר\"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך",
    "event_link": "https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01"
},
{
    "content": {
        "link": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V1sXWx_Jqbn2f_2P40v_DlqlHfXB1u-0/view?usp=sharing",
        "title": "Proceeding Together Vol. 3"
    },
    "id": "month_1_farbrengen_1_content",
    "event_title": "יום א' דר\"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך",
    "event_link": "https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01"
},
{
    "content": {
        "link": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V1sXWx_Jqbn2f_2P40v_DlqlHfXB1u-0/view?usp=sharing",
        "title": "Proceeding Together Vol. 3"
    },
    "id": "month_1_farbrengen_1_content",
    "event_title": "יום א' דר\"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך",
    "event_link": "https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01"
},
{
    "content": {
        "link": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V1sXWx_Jqbn2f_2P40v_DlqlHfXB1u-0/view?usp=sharing",
        "title": "Proceeding Together Vol. 3"
    },
    "id": "month_1_farbrengen_1_content",
    "event_title": "יום א' דר\"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך",
    "event_link": "https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01"
},
{
    "content": {
        "link": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V1sXWx_Jqbn2f_2P40v_DlqlHfXB1u-0/view?usp=sharing",
        "title": "Proceeding Together Vol. 3"
    },
    "id": "month_1_farbrengen_1_content",
    "event_title": "יום א' דר\"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך",
    "event_link": "https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01"
},]
```

This is a samplde data.
I have used all quite a few ways but all of them don't seem to work

Comment: What are the regular ways you are talking about ?

Answer (score 2):

looking at the `dicts` they all have the same id but different `links`. so in this case it's better to remove the duplicates using `link`

```
my_dicts = [{'content': {'link': 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vVIhIn8Omz6fGmeriCDilOlKQhAOBItL', 'title': 'שיחו"ק'}, 'id': 'month_1_farbrengen_1_content', 'event_title': 'יום א\' דר"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך', 'event_link': 'https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01'}, {'content': {'link': 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q6o-wEkpAsvRQIaJqSqcCOkBZhQAAdYI/view?usp=drivesdk', 'title': 'תו"מ התוועדויות'}, 'id': 'month_1_farbrengen_1_content', 'event_title': 'יום א\' דר"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך', 'event_link': 'https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01'}, {'content': {'link': 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V1sXWx_Jqbn2f_2P40v_DlqlHfXB1u-0/view?usp=sharing', 'title': 'Proceeding Together Vol. 3'}, 'id': 'month_1_farbrengen_1_content', 'event_title': 'יום א\' דר"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך', 'event_link': 'https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01'}, {'content': {'link': 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V1sXWx_Jqbn2f_2P40v_DlqlHfXB1u-0/view?usp=sharing', 'title': 'Proceeding Together Vol. 3'}, 'id': 'month_1_farbrengen_1_content', 'event_title': 'יום א\' דר"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך', 'event_link': 'https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01'}, {'content': {'link': 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V1sXWx_Jqbn2f_2P40v_DlqlHfXB1u-0/view?usp=sharing', 'title': 'Proceeding Together Vol. 3'}, 'id': 'month_1_farbrengen_1_content', 'event_title': 'יום א\' דר"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך', 'event_link': 'https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01'}, {'content': {'link': 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V1sXWx_Jqbn2f_2P40v_DlqlHfXB1u-0/view?usp=sharing', 'title': 'Proceeding Together Vol. 3'}, 'id': 'month_1_farbrengen_1_content', 'event_title': 'יום א\' דר"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך', 'event_link': 'https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01'}, {'content': {'link': 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V1sXWx_Jqbn2f_2P40v_DlqlHfXB1u-0/view?usp=sharing', 'title': 'Proceeding Together Vol. 3'}, 'id': 'month_1_farbrengen_1_content', 'event_title': 'יום א\' דר"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך', 'event_link': 'https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01'}]
new_dict = []
n_urls = set()

for i in range(len(my_dicts)):
  if not my_dicts[i]['content']['link'] in n_urls:
    new_dict.append(my_dicts[i])
    n_urls.add(my_dicts[i]['content']['link'])
  
print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
  [
   {'content': {'link': 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vVIhIn8Omz6fGmeriCDilOlKQhAOBItL',
   'title': 'שיחו"ק'},
  'event_link': 'https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01',
  'event_title': 'יום א\' דר"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך',
  'id': 'month_1_farbrengen_1_content'},

   {'content': {'link': 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q6o-wEkpAsvRQIaJqSqcCOkBZhQAAdYI/view?usp=drivesdk',
   'title': 'תו"מ התוועדויות'},
  'event_link': 'https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01',
  'event_title': 'יום א\' דר"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך',
  'id': 'month_1_farbrengen_1_content'},

   {'content': {'link': 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V1sXWx_Jqbn2f_2P40v_DlqlHfXB1u-0/view?usp=sharing',
   'title': 'Proceeding Together Vol. 3'},
  'event_link': 'https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01',
  'event_title': 'יום א\' דר"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך',
  'id': 'month_1_farbrengen_1_content'}]
```

Comment: I think it's better to save url with set.

Comment: I agree with you but not necessary in this case. it should be only when you intend to make use of the `urls set` later in your code. but in this case I only use it to remove duplicate. And the purpose of putting a `url` in a set is to remove duplicates, but that not the target here

Comment: I think it's necessary. It will reduce the time complexity from O(n^2) to O(n).

Comment: you're correct, I've updated the code to make use of set in storing the urls

Comment: you earn my respect sir!!!! big thanks

Answer (score 1):

If `lst` is your list from the question you can remove duplicates for example with:

```py
out = []
while lst:
    item = lst.pop()
    if item not in out:
        out.append(item)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {
        "content": {
            "link": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V1sXWx_Jqbn2f_2P40v_DlqlHfXB1u-0/view?usp=sharing",
            "title": "Proceeding Together Vol. 3",
        },
        "id": "month_1_farbrengen_1_content",
        "event_title": "יום א' דר\"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך",
        "event_link": "https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01",
    },
    {
        "content": {
            "link": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q6o-wEkpAsvRQIaJqSqcCOkBZhQAAdYI/view?usp=drivesdk",
            "title": 'תו"מ התוועדויות',
        },
        "id": "month_1_farbrengen_1_content",
        "event_title": "יום א' דר\"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך",
        "event_link": "https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01",
    },
    {
        "content": {
            "link": "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vVIhIn8Omz6fGmeriCDilOlKQhAOBItL",
            "title": 'שיחו"ק',
        },
        "id": "month_1_farbrengen_1_content",
        "event_title": "יום א' דר\"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך",
        "event_link": "https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01",
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

first we create a `newItems` array.
then we loop through our items and everytime check if current item is in the `newItems` array or not. if its not there we simple add it to `newItems`.

```py
newItems = []

for item in items:
    if item not in newItems:
        newItems.append(item)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to future readers to add some more explanation to your answer rather than just a bare code block.

Comment: The code is pretty self explanatory !

Comment: Although it might look like that to us, people looking at this later on might not know :) you can just quickly say “this adds it to the other list if it is not already there”

Comment: @AmiraliAmirifar I tried this  but this throws an error that  dict is not hashable since you can't actually traverse through a dict or compare them as strings

Comment: which version of python are you using @myself_rana.raj

Comment: Python 3.10.4 @AmiraliAmirifar

Answer (score 1):

Since the format of your dictionary looks fixed, you can wrap it a little:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self, dct):
...         self.dct = dct
...         self.link = dct['content']['link']
...     def __hash__(self):
...         return hash(self.link)
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return self.link == other.link if isinstance(other, Foo) else False
...
>>> [f.dct for f in {Foo(dct) for dct in dict_list}]
[{'content': {'link': 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vVIhIn8Omz6fGmeriCDilOlKQhAOBItL',
              'title': 'שיחו"ק'},
  'id': 'month_1_farbrengen_1_content',
  'event_title': 'יום א\' דר"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך',
  'event_link': 'https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01'},
 {'content': {'link': 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q6o-wEkpAsvRQIaJqSqcCOkBZhQAAdYI/view?usp=drivesdk',
              'title': 'תו"מ התוועדויות'},
  'id': 'month_1_farbrengen_1_content',
  'event_title': 'יום א\' דר"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך',
  'event_link': 'https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01'},
 {'content': {'link': 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V1sXWx_Jqbn2f_2P40v_DlqlHfXB1u-0/view?usp=sharing',
              'title': 'Proceeding Together Vol. 3'},
  'id': 'month_1_farbrengen_1_content',
  'event_title': 'יום א\' דר"ה, בעת ההליכה לתשליך',
  'event_link': 'https://www.mafteiach.app/all/5711-01-01'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[i for i in l if l.count(i)==1 ]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved to future readers if you added some explanation for the code.